# How do I get SBT staging directory at build time?

Tags: scala, sbt

How do I get SBT staging directory at build time?

I want to do a tricky clone of a remote repo, and the `stagingDirectory` of SBT seems to be a nice fit.

How do I get the directory inside "Build.scala" ?

SBT source code:
http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.1/sxr/sbt/BuildPaths.scala.html#sbt.BuildPaths.stagingDirectory

=======

Underlying problem NOT directly relevant to the question. I wanted to use a subdirectory of a git dependency in SBT. SBT doesn't provide this out of the box so I wrote a simple wrapper:

```scala
object Git {

  def clone(cloneFrom: String, branch: String, subdirectory: String) = {
    val uniqueHash = Hash.halfHashString(cloneFrom + branch)
    val cloneTo = file(sys.props("user.home")) / ".sbt" / "staging" / uniqueHash

    val clonedDir = creates(cloneTo) {
      Resolvers.run("git", "clone", cloneFrom, cloneTo.absolutePath)
      Resolvers.run(Some(cloneTo), "git", "checkout", "-q", branch)
    }

    clonedDir / subdirectory
  }
}
```

usage:

`lazy val myDependency = Git.clone(cloneFrom = "git://...someproject.git", branch = "v2.4", subdirectory = "someModule")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the API from your link, there are two methods you can use `getGlobalBase` and `getStagingDirectory`, both take state.

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import sbt.BuildPaths._

object MyBuild extends Build {

  val outputStaging = taskKey[Unit]("Outputs staging")

  lazy val root = project.in(file(".")).settings(
    outputStaging := {
      val s = state.value
      println(getStagingDirectory(s, getGlobalBase(s)))

    }
  )

}
```

### Edit

After your last comment, I think you're looking for a [custom resolver](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.2/docs/Extending/Build-Loaders.html#custom-resolver). The custom resolver has an access to a [ResolveInfo](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.2/api/index.html#sbt.BuildLoader%24%24ResolveInfo) object, which has a property called `staging`.

For example this is how you could achieve what you're looking for (actually without accessing `staging` directly):

```
object MyBuild extends Build {

  lazy val root = project.in(file(".")).dependsOn(RootProject(uri("dir+git://github.com/lpiepiora/test-repo.git#branch=master&dir=subdir")))

  override def buildLoaders = BuildLoader.resolve(myCustomGitResolver) +: super.buildLoaders

  def myCustomGitResolver(info: BuildLoader.ResolveInfo): Option[() => File] =
    if(info.uri.getScheme != "dir+git") None
    else {
      import RichURI.fromURI
      val uri = info.uri
      val (branch, directory) = parseOutBranchNameAndDir(uri.getFragment)
      val gitResolveInfo = new BuildLoader.ResolveInfo(
        uri.copy(scheme = "git", fragment = branch), info.staging, info.config, info.state
      )
      println(uri.copy(scheme = "git", fragment = branch))
      Resolvers.git(gitResolveInfo).map(fn => () => fn() / directory)
    }

  // just an ugly way to get the branch and the folder
  // you may want something more sophisticated
  private def parseOutBranchNameAndDir(fragment: String): (String, String) = {
    val Array(branch, dir) = fragment.split('&')
    (branch.split('=')(1), dir.split('=')(1))
  }

}
```

The idea is that we delegate to the predefined git resolver, and we let it do it's work, after it's done, we'll return a subdirectory: `fn() / directory`.

This is an example and of course you could stick to your logic of getting the repository. The *staging directory* will be available to you in the resolver method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, this doesn't exactly solve what I'm trying to do. I wanted to access `stagingDirectory` outside of any task. (I wanted to git-pull some of the dependencies and provide them as `dependsOn`.)

Comment: Are those projects sbt based? I guess you know of this http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.2/docs/Dormant/Full-Configuration.html#project-references, right? There is also an update task, you can run it there.

Comment: I mean, this is the best answer I know, thanks a lot for it. But if there is a way without any tasks -- that would be very nice.

Comment: Yes, they are SBT-based. I'm aware that SBT can handle git dependencies, but I need a slightly trickier thing, I want to use a subdirectory of a cloned repo.

Comment: So, I tried (and succeeded) to write a similar manual git-pull. But I was forced to hard-code the staging dir: `val cloneTo = file(sys.props("user.home")) / ".sbt" / "staging" / uniqueHash`

Comment: I see, but when do you access it? I mean when is the actual cloning done? There are several hooks you could attach it to, depends when do you want it to be done? e.g. if you added that to update. Basically you need the state, and it's dynamic, and to my knowledge can be only accessed from commands or tasks

Comment: @VasyaNovikov after your comment / update to the question, I think you're looking for a custom resolver. Please check my updated answer.