# Determine Local Directory for Git Dependency

Tags: scala, sbt

I am using an `ssh` URI reference to treat a remote git repository as a project reference in my `build.sbt`, like so (using `ssh` allows me to access a private repo):

```
lazy val dep = RootProject(uri("ssh://git@github.com/..."))

lazy val root = project(file.in(".").dependsOn(dep)
```

How can I determine, in a task or command in my build file, the local directory that SBT stores the project in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on information found at [How do I get SBT staging directory at build time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23932906/how-do-i-get-sbt-staging-directory-at-build-time), I was able to come up with a solution that works. (SBT 0.13.13)

You need to define a task (or command) so `State` is available, as that allows you to retrieve the staging` directory:

```
lazy val printRepos = taskKey[Unit]("Print path to dependencies that are hosted in git repositories.")
printRepos := {
  import sbt.BuildPaths._

  val s = state.value
  val staging = getStagingDirectory(s, getGlobalBase(s))
  // root is a reference to your top-level project, which has
  // git-hosted dependencies.

  val repos = gitRepos(staging, root.dependencies)
  println("${repos.mkString(",")}")
}
```

The `gitRepos` method (below) takes the staging directory and dependencies, filters for those that look like git repos, and returns a sequence of tuples pairing the project, its original URI, and the local path holding the source.

The actual directory used to store the source locally is returned by `Resolvers.git`, which requires a `ResolveInfo` object. `gitRepos` constructs a malformed `ResolveInfo` in order to re-use Resolvers.git, but I don't think you can get around that:

```
def gitRepos(staging: File, cps: Seq[ClasspathDep[ProjectReference]]): Seq[(ProjectReference, URI, File)] = {
  import sbt.BuildLoader._
  import sbt.RichURI._

  val x = cps.flatMap(cp => Reference.uri(cp.project).map(uri => (cp.project, uri)))
  x.flatMap({ case (project, uri) => {
    // Stolen from sbt.RetrieveUnit
    if(uri.getScheme == "git" || uri.withoutMarkerScheme.getPath.endsWith(".git")) {
      val y = Resolvers.git(new ResolveInfo(uri, staging, null, null))
      y.map(path => (project, uri, path()))
    }
    else
      None
  }})
}
```

Because `getRepos` re-uses `Resolvers.git`, `printRepos` will always print the exact directory that `sbt` will use to store the project reference.

Answer (score 1):

The information is hidden in the `localBase` field of the build unit. You can make a task to get it for the current project:

```
val localBase: TaskKey[File] = taskKey[File]("the local base of project")
localBase := {
  val extracted = Project.extract(state.value)
  extracted.currentUnit.localBase
}
```

For projects you add as `ProjectRef`, it needs to be added as a setting for that project:

```
localBase in yourProjectRef := ...
```

To just get a map of all the local bases:

```
val allYourBase = taskKey[Map[URI,File]]("project bases")
allYourBase := {
  val extracted = Project extract state.value
  extracted.structure.units.map { case (uri, unit) => (uri,unit.localBase)}
}
```